# how to retrive data from multiple table in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, eloquent

```
Model relation
---------------------
language.php
----
public function attributeDetail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AttributeDetail::class, 'language_id');
}

attribute.php
----
public function attributeDetail()
{
    return $this->hasMany(AttributeDetail::class, 'attribute_id');
}

attributeDetail.php
----
public function language()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Language::class);
}
public function attribute()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Attribute::class);
}
```

I want to show the json object like this

```
{
  'attribute_id' => 101,
  'available_language' => [
    {'id' => 1,'language_name' => 'English'},
    {'id' => 2,'language_name' => 'French'}
  ],
}
```

table structure:

```
languages(`id`, `language_name`, `translate_version`, `is_default`, `status`);
attributes(`id`, `required`, `type`, `status`);
attributedetails(id`, `attribute_id`, `language_id`, `attribute_name`, `status`);
```

Comment: What is the existing code you come up with so far

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try somthing like this,

```
$results =  Attribute::select('id')->with(['attributeDetail.language' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('id', 'language_name');
}])->get();
```