# Get data from multiple table in Laravel 5.7 (Eloquent)

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5.7. I have three MySQL table, named : **movies, movie_directors, movie_actors**. I am having issues with retrieving data from these tables. Look at my table structure:

```
movies
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |   title       |   release |  img_url        |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |  Avengers     |    2019   |    #            |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  2    |  Avatar       |    2009   |    #            |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  3    |  Titanic      |    1997   |    #            |
|-----------------------------------------------------|

directors
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |   movie_id  |   dir_name      |  add_date   |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |    1        |  Anthony Russo  |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  2    |    1        |    Joe Russo    |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  3    |    2        |    Cameron      |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|

actors
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |   movie_id  |   act_name      |  add_date   |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |    1        |  Robert Downey  |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  2    |    1        |   Chris Evans   |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  3    |    1        |  Mark Ruffalo   |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  4    |    1        |   Chris Pratt   |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  5    |    2        |   Worthington   |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  6    |    2        |    Weaver       |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|  7    |    2        |    Saldana      |  2019/02/18 |
|-----------------------------------------------------|

I Want
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|   id  |   title       |   release |  img_url    |        directors           |                        actors                              |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  1    |  Avengers     |    2019   |    #        | Anthony Russo, Joe Russo   |  Robert Downey, Chris Evans, Mark Ruffalo, Chris Pratt     | 
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2    |  Avatar       |    2009   |    #        |     Cameron                |  Worthington, Weaver, Saldana                              |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3    |  Titanic      |    1997   |    #        |                            |                                
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Current Code I am using:

```
$movie_list = DB::table('movies')
            ->select('movies.*', 'movie_directors.*', 'movie_actors.*', 'movie_genres.*', 'movie_links.*', 'movie_types.*')
            ->join('movie_directors','movies.id', '=','movie_directors.movie_id')
            ->join('movie_actors', 'movies.id', '=', 'movie_actors.movie_id')
            ->where('movies.status',1)
            ->paginate(50)
            ;
```

Look at the table 'I want' at the bottom of the code. This is what I want.
**Please** don't attach the link below as proof of already answered. It doesn't match with my requirement
[how to retrive data from multiple table in laravel eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44018746/how-to-retrive-data-from-multiple-table-in-laravel-eloquent)

Comment: How did you try to retrieve data? Do you have any piece of code?

Comment: @VadimSirbu , Just added the code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve this you need to group results by movies.id and use `group_concat` to extract results comma concatenated. Your code should look something like this:

```
$movie_list = DB::table('movies')
    ->select(
        'movies.*', 
        DB::raw('group_concat(movie_directors.dir_name) as directors'),
        DB::raw('group_concat(movie_actors.act_name) as actors')
    )
    ->join('movie_directors','movies.id', '=','movie_directors.movie_id')
    ->join('movie_actors', 'movies.id', '=', 'movie_actors.movie_id')
    ->where('movies.status',1)
    ->groupBy('movies.id')
    ->paginate(50)
    ;
```

You can read more about `group_concat` here: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php

Comment: returns this error msg : `Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'mvz.movie_genres' ` ..... any idea?

Comment: I just adjusted the code you provided, I am not aware what tables your have. I would assume you should delete following from your select `'movie_genres.*'`, `'movie_links.*'`,`'movie_types.*'`

Comment: Also in your description you mentioned table names as `directors` and `actors`, but in your query you use `movie_directors` and  `movie_actors`.

Comment: `movie_directors` and `movie_actors` these are the actual table names. And I also removed other tables from the query as you mentioned. Now I get this error : `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mvz.movies.title' isn't in GROUP BY...`

Comment: Could you please try this one and see if you get any results:
`$movie_list = DB::table('movies')
    ->select(
        'movies.id', 
        'movies.title', 
        DB::raw('group_concat(movie_directors.dir_name) as directors'),
        DB::raw('group_concat(movie_actors.act_name) as actors')
    )
    ->join('movie_directors','movies.id', '=','movie_directors.movie_id')
    ->join('movie_actors', 'movies.id', '=', 'movie_actors.movie_id')
    ->where('movies.status',1)
    ->groupBy('movies.id', 'movies.title')
    ->paginate(50)
    ;`

Comment: Again that disappointing error. This time it's : `Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'mvz.movies.release_year' isn't in GROUP BY `

Comment: Please change `movies.*` to `'movies.id', 'movies.title', `

Comment: I did it... Anything else you found suspicious?

Comment: almost worked. But why is it showing each director name several times, i.e  - `Bilall Fallah,Adil El Arbi,Bilall Fallah,Adil El Arbi,Bilall Fallah,Adil El Arbi,Bilall Fallah,Adil El Arbi`

Comment: One more thing you can try is change the group by from `->groupBy('movies.id', 'movies.title')` to `->groupBy('movies.id', 'movies.title', 'movie_directors.movie_id', 'movie_actors.movie_id')`. If this does not give the expected results, I give up.

Comment: problem is solved. Your code is correct. I just had to do some little tweaking according to my situation. Which is : I had to select all the necessary columns from `movies` table and at the end, I had to put all the columns again inside `groupBy( )` method. And also to avoid data redundancy, I used `DISTINCT`.. Thank you very much. I am marking your answer as correct.